# Drawing folding/collapsible sections in an Operator's Undo panel?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, operator, panel

I'm making an operator that is getting big in terms of properties and options. I thought about separating those properties into different kind of tabs that depending the selection, X or Y properties are drawn.

For that I thought about making an `EnumProperty` that decides what is being drawn, like:

[image]

My problem is that changing this enum triggers the operator's `execute()`, and since this EnumProperty has nothing to do about the operator's behaviour, I don't want the user to wait until the operator has been re-executed to change the "tab"/section (also, my operator is getting a bit heavy in terms of computing).

This question is a reformulation of [this (where I asked if it was possible to avoid that changing a property retriggers the Operator)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/306434/prevent-that-changing-an-operators-property-retriggers-the-operator), but I thought it may be missleading and maybe Blender UI offers a different solutions for that.

Any idea?